# Why can't I see my mp3 files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Guten tag everybody.

I'm new to Python and am trying to re-create a simple mp3 player.

When I run the code below the UI pops up and asks for a directory, but when I navigate to where my mp3 files are located I get the message "no items match your search". I can navigate to and play all my files without issue through normal file explorer.

When I click on cancel, I get the error "OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '' "

I'm on a Windows 10 machine, using Python 3.6. I'm using Sublime with Anaconda to run the code.

I have looked through google, stack, youtube, documentation and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import os

import pygame
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.minsize(300, 300)

songList = []

index = 0

def directorychooser():

    directory = askdirectory()
    os.chdir(directory)

    for files in os.listdir(directory):
       if files.endswith('mp3'):
           songList.append(files)
           print("songList")


directorychooser()
```

Comment: Is that indentation correct? Did you intend for the `for files in ...` line to be inside the `directorychooser()` function?

Comment: With correct indentation, this does not create an error for me. (Indentation as glibud mention)

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the path you are choosing? What does the path look like?

Comment: Sorry about that. The 'for files in' is inside the 'directorychooser()' function in my code, but I messed up the formatting when adding to Stack.

Comment: The path I'm selecting is "C:\Users\BuggD\Desktop\Dev Projects\Python Projects\MediaPlayer\Music"

Comment: I updated the code to reflect what I actually have in Sublime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check if the path you are choosing is an absolute (starting with 'C:\') or relative path. If it's absolute it should work.

However if it's relative (for example 'Music' in the current folder), changing directory (`chdir`) before listing will not work. You should print it.

You should try to remove the `os.chdir` call which is not required except in very specific cases.

You can also change the path to an absolute path:

```
directory = os.path.abspath(directory)
```

Before doing the `os.chdir` of course.

For the cancel case, you should verify it the directory exists (It will return None if you hit cancel):

```
if directory:
    <Look for files>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Also I made a mistake with the code format when adding in Stack. I updated the code in the question, does this still apply?

Comment: I edited my answer now that the indentation is correct.

Comment: Thanks You! I am using absolute path. Removing the os.chdir got rid of the ""OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '' " " but then when I ran the code it would give me the error "The system could not find the path specified" when I cancel. After I received that error I realized I was only supposed to be choosing the directory the files were in. I'm embarrassed because I didn't recognize that earlier... but I guess taking a break and coming back to it is sometimes necessary. I really appreciate your help with this.